# Manage Intel RAID in Windows

Tags: windows, raid

I have a box with Intel C600 Series Chipset SATA RAID Controller. Three RAID1 sets were configured at built time and Windows 2008 Server was installed on one of the RAID sets. The box has been functioning as a production SQL Server for the past 6 months.

I would like to view/manage this machine's RAID configuration from Windows. What software do I need to install?

I looked into Intel RST and Matrix Storage Manager but I am still not sure. If I open the link for [Intel RST](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/sftwr-prod/imsm) and then go to the Latest Downloads I am presented with a list of software, most of which end with the words "RAID driver". Is that going to give me access to a Windows app for managing Intel RAID controller or is it just the driver? If the latter, what's the download for the app?

*The Matrix downloads seem to be all very old -- the latest is from 2009.*

Comment: Search on this site for 'fake raid' for tales of woe and regret

Comment: Server 2008 is even older!

Comment: Are you saying Matrix Storage Manager is what I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

"Fake RAID" is a horrible, horrible thing and you should realize that this will probably end in frustration and a fine scotch for you just like it did for [me](https://serverfault.com/questions/308785/how-to-monitor-an-adaptec-intel-ich10r-raid-controller-any-snmp-notification-op). See David Spillet's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/245928/does-fake-raid-offer-any-advantage-over-software-raid/264418#264418) on SuperUser for details but in summation it combines the disadvantages of hardware RAID controllers and the disadvantages of software RAID implementation. Which is pretty sweet.

*BUT*, if you would prefer to continue your best bet will be RSTe. If you look at Intel's site for the [C600](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/server-chipsets/server-chipset-c600.html) you'll see they list [Rapid Storage Technology enterprise (Intel® RSTe)](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/chpsts/rste) as providing, "...management tools as well as RAID options to improve performance and reliability in local storage." which sounds like what you're after. You can download the latest version [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22139&ProdId=3449&lang=eng). Best of luck.

[image: Intel RST Download]

Comment: Latest RST download is now at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25165/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-RAID-Driver

Comment: Latest RSTe download at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25393/Intel-RSTe-AHCI-SCU-Software-RAID-driver-for-Windows-